# Wordpress post tags in menu

Tags: wordpress, tags, taxonomy

I can`t add post tags to wordpress menu. I try create taxonomy, with replace "post_tag", but it not showing on Appearance->Menus. When i create custom taxonomy, it showing on Menu section. How to add standart wordpress tags to menu? Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to Appearance -> Menus and press "Screen Options" in the top right corner of the page. Check the box for "Tags" and a new section will appear for you to add tags to the menu.

Comment: What version of your wordpress. Trying to figure out where to find this Screen Options.

Comment: @MaXi32 This should apply to any version of WordPress (at least any version released over the past few years). Be aware that plugins or your active theme could be altering what's displayed in the admin.

Comment: I just hate Wordpress so much.